# MapControl.ActualCameraChanged doesn't always trigger

Tags: c#, events, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm working on a UWP project where I render 3D content on top of a tilted BingMaps map.

I'm rendering my 3d content using directx in a seperate (partially transparent) control that lies on top of the map. So it's not rendered within or as part of the mapcontrol or anything, it's completely seperate.

In order to (try to) make the 3d-camera match the map-camera, I use the ActualCameraChanged event to determine when to update and render my 3d camera.

Now I noticed that sometimes when I start the map, the ActualCameraChanged-event is never triggered. I get no warnings or errors or nothing, everything seems to work fine, but the event just doesn't get triggered.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a bug in the current version of the map control. You might try using the LoadingStatusChanged event instead.

Comment: That doesn't trigger nearly as often (and just not at the right time) as needed. (for example, when I make the camera spin around a place, it just doesn't trigger, while it should trigger constantly)